# C++ Array Element Memory Alignment

Tags: c++, arrays, alignment

Hi i've tried to give an array of for example point light positions to a shader. But this shader wants the vec3s to be aligned by 16 bytes not the 12 bytes from glm. For one vec3 there was no problem, you could just put "alignas(16)" in front of it. But for an array c++ just thinks that the whole array should be aligned by 16 and not its individual elements.

```
struct Scene {
   alignas(16) glm::vec3 lights[2];
};

int main() {
  Scene scene;
  scene.lights[0] = { 1,2,3 };
  scene.lights[1] = { 4,5,6 };
}
```

I've also looked into the memory debugger in visual studio and the bytes are just tightly packed without any padding

[Screenshot of visual studio memory debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnpWi.png)

The only solutions i can think of is **one**: Changing the source code of glm to an alignment of 16 (*which isn't a good idea*)

**two**: to create a new struct like "16ByteAlignedVec3" , which contains the vec3, and setting this struct to have an alignment of 16. And then use this as the type of the array.

and **three**: Using an pointer to acces the array data and incrementing it by 16 bytes if you want to acces for example index 1

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But for an array c++ just thinks that the whole array should be aligned by 16 and not its individual elements.

Indeed. That is what specifying `alignas` for an array means. The alignment of the array is affected; not the alignment of the elements.

> two: to create a new struct like "16ByteAlignedVec3" , which contains the vec3, and setting this struct to have an alignment of 16

This is a reasonable approach. You can make the class behave same as if it was glm::vec3 by using inheritance instead of a member:

```
struct Scene {
    struct alignas(16) 16ByteAlignedVec3 : glm::vec3 {};
    aligned_vec3 lights[2];
};
```